# Angular 2 RC5 configure providers before bootstrapping application

Tags: angular

I have some external data that I need to bring in via http request to configure a base URL for some of my API endpoints. With the move to RC5 and the somewhat new bootstrapping process, I'm having trouble dynamically configuring a provider along with the bootstrap code. Prior to RC5, you could do something like this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
        provide("config", {useValue: config})
    ]);
```

and have the above code in the body of a promise `then` or `Observable` subscription body. I would then use the provided value in a service that calls my API by doing something like:

```
export class AppService {
    constructor(@Inject('config') private configObj) {}
}
```

How can this be done in angular 2 RC5? My thought would be to do some async work to have the observable subscription look like

```
data.subscribe((config)=>{platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);});
```

with the config data being passed into bootstrapModule somehow. I've been all through the docs and can't find an example of this. I also found this github issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10995 but the solution doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated!